# Sound Questions in Pygame

Tags: audio, pygame, volume

1. How can I set a sound's volume?
2. Is it possible to play two sounds at once?
3. Can I know if the music is over using 'if~'?

Comment: Please ask only one question at once and also search through the documentation and Stack Overflow in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in my mind next time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass a value between 0 and 1 to the [`set_volume`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume) method of the sound, e.g.: `sound.set_volume(0.5)`.
2. Just call the play methods of the sounds successively.

   ```
   sound1.play()
   sound2.play()
   ```

   The default number of channels for sound playback is 8, but it can be changed with [`pygame.mixer.set_num_channels`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.set_num_channels).
3. [`pygame.mixer.music.get_busy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy)